# Background image not respecting the width of the page (bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm going crazy.

I am creating a section that has 4 boxes with photos inside. Two in top and two below.

For that I am using the bootstrap.

This section is breaking my layout, and I no longer know what to do. I can not find the error.[image]

Note that the boxes on the right are not respecting the page width.

I'm using bootstrap, but i already setup the padding: 0;.

HTML:

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>
```

CSS:

```
.booking-2 {
  background: #000;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.booking-2 .col-md-6 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
.booking-2 .booking-photo {
  display: block;
  height: 320px;
  background-color: #373c40;
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.booking-2 .booking-1 { background: url('../images/capa.png'); }
.booking-2 .booking-2 { background: url('../images/capa.png'); }
.booking-2 .booking-3 { background: url('../images/capa.png'); }
.booking-2 .booking-4 { background: url('../images/capa.png'); }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x908tt16/embedded/result/

Comment: can you post a jsfiddle maam?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x908tt16/ see in full window

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/x908tt16/embedded/result/

Comment: Is it wrapped in class="container"?

Comment: i dont want the class container because I need them to appear in the corner of the window

Comment: sorry I don't get the question. You're main problem?

Comment: visit the fiddle i just post. If you go to the right side , you will realize that the boxes are disrespecting the browser limit. I need the boxes fit 100 % in the width of the browser. I put an orange line to help understand.

Comment: What browser are you using? Chrome works as it should.

Comment: chrome. Can you post a photo? are u going to the right side of the window? @JimmyRare

Comment: What's the question? Is it solved? If yes, please post and mark as correct. ty

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="booking-photo booking-1 wow bounceInLeft">
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

I believe you need to put the 3rd and 4th image on a new row.

Answer (score 0):

Try my solution

I have done two things

- I have put the the last two images in a new `<div class="row">`
- I have modified the CSS by adding two custom classes to achieve the result

*Removed*

```
.booking-2 .col-md-6 {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

*Added*

```
        .leftColumn {
            padding-right: 0px;
        }
        .rightColumn {               
            padding-left: 0px;
```

Here is the updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x908tt16/2/)**

Comment: But note that this solution still make the page with a space in the right side.